# Setting up a "!stoponexception" condition for windbg via command line / startup script?

Tags: windbg, debugger

I have a problem with an application we've made that sometimes crash with a StackOverflowException in some .NET code.

Unfortunately, the app is partly unmanaged and partly managed, and for some reason the problem only exhibits itself on non-developer machines.

My current plan is to use WINDBG (part of the Debugging Tools for Windows from Microsoft), installed on the testers machines, I can get WINDBG to trap the creation of the exception in question.

As such, I can do the following:

```
sxe ld:mscorlib
g
.loadby sos clr
!stoponexception -create System.StackOverflowException
g
```

Unfortunately, since this problem only crops up every other day, and only every 50+ execution or so, I'd rather avoid having the testers having to type in all or part of this for every time they start this app.

I tried placing the above commands in a text file and created a shortcut for them like this:

```
"...\windbg.exe" -c "$<c:\windbg.txt" -o "...\app.exe"
```

This starts the WINDBG debugger, but unfortunately fails with this error message:

```
0:000> sxe ld:mscorlib
0:000> g
Command file caused an implicit wait
Command file execution failed, HRESULT 0x80004005
    "Unspecified error"
```

So apparently, `g` is not allowed in such a startup script.

Is it possible to do what I want? Can I automate this, or do I just have to prepare a batch file or something that uses autohotkey that does this?

Answer (score 1):

Although it is late but I wanted to provide a workaround nevertheless. I have faced the same problem and I stumbled upon this question while searching for the answer. I have later found out a workaround.

The workaround is to call the script using $>< or $$>< or $$>a< so that the commands are condensed into single command block.

[Here is the windbg help doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TwoN.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You could try `.dump /ma /u c:\app.dmp` so that you get a crash dump which can be copied and analyzed on your machine.

However, instead of trying to let the user run WinDbg on his machine, you can take a crash dump automatically using WER, copy it to your machine and then analyze without time pressure. See [Collecting user-mode dumps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to create settings in the Registry which store the dump on disk.

In both cases you should copy from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 (or Framework64):

- [mscordacwks.dll and rename it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093494/windbg-x64-cannot-debug-a-crash-dump-failed-to-load-data-access-dll)
- [SOS.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251082/windbg-expects-different-version-of-mscordacwks-dll)

Otherwise it might happen that your .NET version differs from his version and you can't analyze the bug.